Palabra plural para padres (hombres)
He escrito esta oración:
“Los padres de todos los personajes están ausentes.”
En el cuento a cuál refiero, hay algunos personajes con madres ausentes, y otros con madres presentes, pero ninguno tiene un padre, es decir, un progenitor hombre, presente. ¿Esta oración comunica efectivamente esa idea? Me parece que no. De lo que entiendo, "padre" como palabra singular se refiere más claramente a un hombre, mientras "padres" plural puede hablar de parejas de ambos sexos. ¿Pero, no hay manera concisa y efectiva de hablar sobre múltiples padres, excluyendo madres de la categoría?

Utilizaría alguna alternativa. Ejemplo:

Los progenitores paternos de todos los personajes están ausentes.


La figura paterna de todos los personajes está ausente.


+1 Me gusta más la segunda opción
